# AVAudioPlayer on Lock Screen

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, background-audio, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I've implemented an audio player using **`AVAudioPlayer`** (not *`AVPlayer`*). I'm able to handle the remote control events with the following method. It works quite alright so far, however I see two more `subtypes` for these events: `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingForward` and `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingBackward`.

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay)
        {
            [self playAudio];
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause)
        {
            [self pauseAudio];
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause)
        {
            [self togglePlayPause];
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingBackward)
        {
            [self rewindTheAudio]; //this method rewinds the audio by 15 seconds.
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingForward)
        {
            [self fastForwardTheAudio]; //this method fast-forwards the audio by 15 seconds.
        }

}
```

**So the questions:**

1. In order to have things work right, am I supposed to implement those two subtypes, too?
2. This method only enables the `rewind`, `play/pause`, and `fast forward` buttons on lock screen, but it doesn't display the file title, artwork, and duration. How can I display that info using `AVAudioPlayer` or `AVAudioSession` (I don't really want one more library/API to implement this)?

   2-a. I discovered `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` while searching and I don't know much about it. Do I have to use it to implement those stuff above? :-[

Comment: What was the down vote for, exactly??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct, `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` is the only way to do this. So go ahead and link with `MediaPlayer.framework`. In the class that handles playing tracks, import `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`. Whenever your track changes, do this:

```
NSDictionary *info = @{ MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: artistName,
                            MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: albumName,
                            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: songName };

    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = info;
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick; but how about the first question? Are they supposed to be implemented, too?